# why is my dplyr statement creating extra rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want 'temp' to output 40 rows consisting of males age 1-20 and females age 1-20. Instead it's creating the 40 rows then copying them and appending them resulting in 'temp' being 80 rows.

Why is it doing this and how do I stop it? I know I can remove rows 41-80 myself but this is a pain when working with big datasets.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gender <- sample(c("male","female"), 100, replace = T)
age <- sample(1:20, , replace = T)

df <- data.frame(gender, age)

temp <- df %>% group_by(gender, age) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  complete(gender = c("male", "female"), age = 1:20, fill = list(count = 0))
```

Comment: Is this giving you the desired output `df %>% group_by(gender, age) %>%
 summarise(count = n()) %>%
 group_by(gender) %>%
 complete(age = 1:20, fill = list(count = 0))`?

Comment: Thanks that works. Also taking group_by(gender) out works. I thought without specifying gender in complete() then if there were say no age 2 for either female or male it would just create age 2 for female with a 0 count but it wouldn't create age 2 for male because i'm telling it that age 2 has to be in there (but only has to be once). I think i understand now that by having gender in group_by() it MUST HAVE male AND female for each of the ages... in this case 1:20 because i've specified that in complete(). I'm still not sure why having gender in complete() creates the extra rows though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From dplyr's [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) (emphasis added):

> When you group by multiple variables, each summary peels off **one
>   level** of the grouping.

The following is the data frame your code piped into `complete`:

```
> df %>% group_by(gender, age) %>% summarise(count = n()) 
# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   gender [?]
   gender   age count
   <fct>  <int> <int>
 1 female     2     4
 2 female     3     2
 3 female     7     6
 4 female     9     5
 5 female    10     4
 6 female    11     2
 7 female    12     3
 8 female    13     4
 9 female    15     1
10 female    18     1
# ... with 14 more rows
```

We can see that after one round of `summarise`, the data frame is no longer grouped by `age`, but it is still grouped by `gender`. This means at the next step, it will attempt to complete all combinations of gender (M/F) and age (1-20) ***within*** each group, leading to 40 rows of combinations for each gender. With 2 genders, we thus get 40 x 2 = 80 rows in total.

The approaches following would be equivalent in giving the expected result:

```
# explicitly remove all grouping
t1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(gender, age) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(gender = c("male", "female"), 
           age = 1:20, 
           fill = list(count = 0))

# retain gender grouping, & only complete for different ages within each gender group
t2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(gender, age) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  complete(age = 1:20, 
           fill = list(count = 0))

# use count, which is a wrapper for group_by(), summarise(n = n()), & ungroup() in one line
# note: the output variable name from this approach is hard-coded to n, & there is currently
# no way to change it in this step
t3 <- df %>%
  count(gender, age) %>%
  rename(count = n) %>%
  complete(gender = c("male", "female"), 
           age = 1:20, 
           fill = list(count = 0))

> all.equal(t1, t2)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(t1, t3)
[1] TRUE
```